# Цикл while. подсчитать количество монет

Tags: python

В мире ведьмака существуют монеты с номиналами 1,  5, 10, 25

Напишите программу, которая определяет какое минимальное количество чеканных монет нужно заплатить ведьмаку.

Не могу понять где ошибка. Почему код не выполняется и не подсчитывает количество монет.

```
a = int(input())
count = 0
while a > 25:
    a - 25
    count += 1
while a > 10:
    a - 10
    count += 1
while a > 5:
    a - 5
    count += 1
while a > 1:
    a - 1
    count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: Вы никуда не сохраняете результаты вычислений, переменная `a` никогда не изменяется

Comment: `count, a = a // 25, a % 25` и т.д. И никакого while.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, тогда уж https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать это так:

```
coins = [1, 5, 10, 25]
count = 0
a = int(input())
for coin in sorted(coins, reverse=True):
    count += a // coin
    a %= coin
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input())
count = 0
while a >= 25:
    a -= 25
    count += 1
while a >= 10:
    a -= 10
    count += 1
while a >= 5:
    a -= 5
    count += 1
while a >= 1:
    a -= 1
    count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]